# What's the purpose of AP beacons if clients send Probe Requests anyway?

Tags: wireless-networking

Whenever a user scans for nearby Wi-Fi networks to connect to, I assume the client will broadcast a Probe Request, and APs will respond with Probe Responses. So then, what is the purpose of AP beacons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client is sending probe frames and checking for responses, it cannot send or receive data.

In a situation where the client is able to roam on a different channel, the beacons allow the client to listen and find out what's out there on other channels without interrupting any active connections or transfers on the transmitting channel.  In that way better roaming decisions can be made, and roaming can happen without having to interrupt anything with a scan when it needs to.

[Reference](http://www.my80211.com/home/2010/1/11/80211-client-active-and-passive-scanning.html).